# Find the differential equation of the given primitive

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given, $$y=sin(ax)+a;$$where 'a' is any arbitrary constant.

To find its differential equation ,I cannot eliminate 'a' . Please help

Comment: Use the chain rule for the $sin(ax)$. Why can't you eliminate the $+a$? It's a constant, so I think you can.

Comment: @Mastrem I am getting a fourth degree equation in 'a'. It's getting way too complicated.

Comment: Can't you just use $f(x)=sin(ax)+a$ and $f'(x)=cos(a)\cdot a$?

Comment: @Mastrem I think $$y'=a*cos(ax)$$

Comment: @Mastrem And it gives the following equation: $$(y'/a)^2+(y-a)^2=1$$ which is a fourth degree equation in 'a'

Comment: He wants a differential equation, not involving $a$, where the solutions are the functions given.  So $a$ is the arbitrary constant in the solution.

Comment: There is no way to 'eliminate a'

Comment: @TnilkImaniq So there cannot be any differential equation for the above primitive ?

Comment: Of course there are many differential equations were the above is a particular solution

Comment: @TnilkImaniq I don't understand . Can you please give an example of one such differential equation to elaborate your statement?

Answer (score 1):

Since $y^{\prime}=a\cos ax$, $y^{\prime\prime\prime}=-a^3\cos ax=-a^2y^{\prime}$. So
$$a=\sqrt{\frac{-y^{\prime\prime\prime}}{y^{\prime}}}$$
Then
$$y=\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-y^{\prime\prime\prime}}{y^{\prime}}}\cdot x\right)+\sqrt{\frac{-y^{\prime\prime\prime}}{y^{\prime}}}$$
**EDIT**: By way of apology, let me more clearly point out the error in my ways. If we go back to
$$y^{\prime}=a\cos ax$$ $$y^{\prime\prime}=-a^2\sin ax$$ $$a^4-\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2a^2-\left(y^{\prime\prime}\right)^2=0$$
This is easily solved to
$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2\pm\sqrt{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^4+4\left(y^{\prime\prime}\right)^2}}2}$$
If we were to take the $+$ signs above, we would have a differential equation for $y^{\prime}$:
$$y^{\prime}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+\sqrt{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^4+4\left(y^{\prime\prime}\right)^2}}2}\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+\sqrt{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^4+4\left(y^{\prime\prime}\right)^2}}2}\cdot x\right)$$
Now if by some miracle we were able to integrate this to reproduce $y^{\prime}=a\cos ax$, the final integral would be $y=\sin ax+C$, so in general having a higher order differential equation than the number of constants produces, in a sense 'a' differential equation, but not 'the' differential equation.

Comment: I think since the number of arbitrary constant is only one , therefore the order of the differential equation should be 1.

Comment: So that would involve solving that quartic for a and then substituting into the original equation? Doesn't sound pretty...

Comment: The point of this exercise is that $a = C$

Answer (score 0):

One possible equation is

$$y'' + y' + a^2y = a \cos ax + a^3$$

For this equation, any solution must include $\sin ax + a$.

Comment: Is it not necessary that when forming a differential equation , the arbitrary constant (which is 'a' here) must be eliminated? Further, since there is only a single arbitrary constant present , wouldn't the order of the required differential equation must necessarily be 1?

Comment: 'a' is an arbitrary constant in the sense that y is independent of a. However, since your function y is $\sin ax + a$, you can see that $a$ is both the angular frequency and an extra added term

Comment: If $a$ were not present in the differential equation, how exactly would it show up in the way that it does in the primitive?

Comment: I think you can take a look at the equation $$y=sin(ax)$$. Here we can eliminate 'a' and get the following differential equation : $$y=sin(\frac{xy'}{\sqrt{1-y^2}})$$